# A surge of controller errors on \Device\Ide\IdePort0

Tags: event-log, atapi

I made a clean reinstall of my computer yesterday after I seemed to have hard-drive problems.
Now it seems they have returned. My computer freezes for a few seconds every few minutes. I checked the Event log and discovered there was a surge of errors with the following characteristics:

- Level: Error
- Source: atapi
- "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort0."
- Binary Data:
  0000: 00100000 00000001 00000000 C004000B
  0008: 00000004 C0000185 00000000 00000000
  0010: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
  0018: 00000000 00001005

How can I diagnose the problem?
I suspect my 1.5TB drive, but how can I confirm it? Currently I have 2 hard drives in my desktop - one is a brand new SSD and the other is the 1.5TB Western Digital "green" drive.

**UPDATES**

- I don't want to diagnose only which hard drive causes the problem, but also if it's a hard-drive problem, cable problem or chipset problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the one hard drive you can and see if the errors stop. If they don't its the one plugged in, if they do its the one you unplugged.

.